# Passenger start fails with uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, passenger, rvm-capistrano

I am working on automating my Rails deploy with Capistrano and I am encountering an error at the end of the process while starting passenger.
I end up with the following error :

```
uninitialized constant PhusionPassenger::Standalone::Command::SERVER_INSTANCE_DIR_STRUCTURE_MAJOR_VERSION
```

I actually found the `SERVER_INSTANCE_DIR_STRUCTURE_MAJOR_VERSION` constant perfectly defined in `[...]/phusion_passenger/constants.rb`.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
*** [err :: www.example.com] /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/command.rb:241:in `create_nginx_controller'
*** [err :: www.example.com] :
*** [err :: www.example.com] uninitialized constant PhusionPassenger::Standalone::Command::SERVER_INSTANCE_DIR_STRUCTURE_MAJOR_VERSION
*** [err :: www.example.com] (
*** [err :: www.example.com] NameError
*** [err :: www.example.com] )
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:69:in `run'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:93:in `block in run_command'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:48:in `block in each_command'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:43:in `each'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:43:in `each_command'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:91:in `run_command'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:62:in `run!'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:39:in `run!'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.4/bin/passenger:33:in `<top (required)>'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/passenger:23:in `load'
*** [err :: www.example.com] from /var/www/production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/passenger:23:in `<main>'
```

I added custom tasks for starting and stopping Passenger Standalone from Capistrano, and everything seems to go as expected including Passegner's installation, until this strange error. Here is the relevant part of my Capfile :

```
set :passenger_cmd,  "#{fetch(:bundle_cmd, "bundle")} exec passenger"
namespace :deploy do
  task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} && #{passenger_cmd} start -e #{rails_env} -p #{passenger_port} -d"
  end

  task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} && #{passenger_cmd} stop -p #{passenger_port}"
  end

  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run <<-CMD
      if [[ -f #{current_path}/tmp/pids/passenger.#{passenger_port}.pid ]];
      then
        cd #{current_path} && #{passenger_cmd} stop -p #{passenger_port};
      fi
    CMD

    run "cd #{current_path} && #{passenger_cmd} start -e #{rails_env} -p #{passenger_port} -d"
  end
end
```

My complete setup is as following :

- Rails 3.2
- RVM
- Capistrano
- Passenger standalone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would be to downgrade to Passenger 4.0.3.

```
gem uninstall passenger
gem install passenger --version="4.0.3"
```

It looks to be an issue in the 4.0.4 release.

Comment: Yes. This is a bug in 4.0.4. I've opened the following issue: https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=899

Answer (score 2):

The bug is fixed in commit [4ad928d](https://github.com/FooBarWidget/passenger/commit/4ad928da840663e1933c4557c9e79a3166b48304) on GitHub.

You can try to use a clone from the GitHub repository, or wait for version 4.0.5 which will include this fix.

**Edit:** As of this moment version 4.0.5 is available.